# Invalid remote certificate while accessing PayPal Sandbox transaction service

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am testing my application with PayPal sandbox.

The URI I use for the transaction is *https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick.*

In my return page I read the data from PayPal then I form a new string to send back with **cmd = _notify-validate**.
When I make a call to *https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr* I am getting error saying "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

I tried making a call to *https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr* instead and it always return t "INVALID".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an SSL issue: This error message is caused because the process is not being able to validate the Server Certificate supplied by the Server during an HTTPS (SSL) request.  The very first troubleshooting step should be to see if the server supplied certificate and every certificate in the chain is trouble free.